# Manipulate the result of MySQL query into the desired JSON structure in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this table containing data:
[image]
JSON result from query:

```
[{
    "cnt": "1",
    "category_name": "Entertainment",
    "event_name": "Typhoon Sample",
    "year_of_event": "2000"
}, {
    "cnt": "1",
    "category_name": "Heavy Rainfall Warning and Advisory",
    "event_name": "Typhoon Abra",
    "year_of_event": "2015"
}, {
    "cnt": "1",
    "category_name": "Daily Post",
    "event_name": "No Event",
    "year_of_event": " "
}, {
    "cnt": "1",
    "category_name": "Weather Forecast",
    "event_name": "No Event",
    "year_of_event": " "
}, {
    "cnt": "2",
    "category_name": "Actual Docs",
    "event_name": "Holloween",
    "year_of_event": "2018"
}, {
    "cnt": "1",
    "category_name": "Daily Post",
    "event_name": "Holloween",
    "year_of_event": "2018"
}]
```

I'm trying to transform it like this:

```
{
    "category": ["Typhoon Sample 2000", "Typhoon Abra 2015", "No Event ", "Holloween 2018"],
    "series": [{
        "name": "Entertainment",
        "data": ["1",0,0,0]
    }, {
        "name": "Heavy Rainfall Warning and Advisory",
        "data": [0,"1",0,0]
    }, {
        "name": "Daily Post",
        "data": [0,0,"1", "1"]
    }, {
        "name": "Weather Forecast",
        "data": [0,0,"1",0]
    }, {
        "name": "Actual Docs",
        "data": [0,0,0,"2"]
    }]
}
```

What it does is, unique `event_name` is group then based on its position or index, the `series` properties will contain the `name` of each unique categories with the data from the query result. For example, if it does not have value fro `Entertainment` category, that `event_name` will have a value of `0`.

What I've done so far:

```
while($row = $result_select->fetch_assoc()) {
        $evennt = $row["event_name"]." ".$row["year_of_event"];
        if (!in_array($evennt, $dbdata["category"])){
            $dbdata["category"][]=$evennt;
        }

        $ccat = $row["category_name"];
        $category_names = array_column($dbdata["series"], 'name');  
        if (!in_array($ccat, $category_names)){
            $dbdata["series"][] = array(
                 'name' => $ccat,
                 'data' => []
            );
        }
        print_r ($dbdata["series"]);
        echo '<br/>';
        print_r ($dbdata["category"]);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'Current '.$evennt.' --'.$ccat.'<br/>';
        foreach (array_values($dbdata["series"]) as $i => $value)  {

            foreach (array_values($dbdata["category"]) as $ii => $valuee){              

                if(($value["name"] == $ccat) && ($valuee==$evennt ) && ($row["cnt"])){
                    array_push($dbdata["series"][$i]["data"],$row["cnt"]);
                    echo $ii.' : '.$value["name"].' : '.$valuee.' with value '.$row["cnt"].' <br/>';
                }else if (in_array($evennt, $dbdata["category"]) && in_array($ccat, $category_names)){
                    array_push($dbdata["series"][$i]["data"],0);
                    echo $ii.' : '.$value["name"].' : '.$valuee.' without value 0 <br/>';
                }
```

I'm stuck with the `else` statement.
Thanks.

Result from the code above:

```
{
    "category": ["Typhoon Sample 2000", "Typhoon Abra 2015", "No Event ", "Holloween 2018"],
    "series": [{
        "name": "Entertainment",
        "data": ["1", 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        "name": "Heavy Rainfall Warning and Advisory",
        "data": ["1", 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        "name": "Daily Post",
        "data": ["1", 0, 0, 0, "1"]
    }, {
        "name": "Weather Forecast",
        "data": ["1", 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        "name": "Actual Docs",
        "data": ["2", 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }]
}
```

**EDIT**: I might have the wrong title, it's not actually transforming the JSON structure, my problem is how to manipulate the result of my query into the desired JSON structure. Also, The code snippet above does achieve the structure or format but the values in `data` is wrong.

Comment: Please store data in a multidimensional array and then do `json_encode` it will transform the array in to the format as you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have updated my question.

Comment: Firstly, please extract a [mcve], without DB access but mock data and formatted according to PSR standards. Then, "stuck with else statement" is far from a suitable description, elaborate on that. Further, any JSON modification starts with decoding it (it's not JSON anymore then!), then running whatever algorithm you need on the data and then encoding it again. Unless the encoding or decoding is your problem, the fact that it's encoded as JSON at some point can be removed from your question completely! Do that in order to focus on the problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I just want to transform the JSON structure before encoding it and passing it to the client.

Comment: You keep writing "JSON structure" but do you mean JSON or data consisting of simple PHP types that be encoded as JSON easily? JSON is not suitable for modification, use that knowledge to reduce the scope of your problem and question!

Comment: "transform the JSON structure before encoding it"...this makes no sense. Before you encode it, it's not JSON, it' just a PHP array or object. So you can manipulate it in the same ways as any other PHP variable. If you can't fix your code to give the output you want, please explain more clearly what the issue is. "stuck with the else" statement doesn't help us to help you - we don't know exactly what it's outputting currently, or what you expected it to do instead. We'd like to help you, but right now it's not very easy for us to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, you are right, it is NOT a JSON object  yet, that is my main objective to throw a JSON Object with the format that is mentioned above. My present code manipulates the result of the query in which if outputted as JSON to the client has the structure above.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Main objective it to output JSON, of course I had to manipulate the result rows of the query to transform it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok thanks. So you mean that currently the code outputs what you've marked as "JSON result from query", but you want it to output what you've marked as " I'm trying to transform it like this:". Is that correct? Because those two are not even slightly similar to each other. If that's the case, it needs a total re-write. But it seems from a glance that your code cannot be printing the first example. So what I asked was, what does it print now? That way we can see easily the mismatch between the desired and actual output.

Comment: And what specifically is intended to be the purpose of the code inside `else` (I assume you mean `else if` within the foreach, specifically?), since that's where you think the issue lies? It's also not clear to me what the `data` array within your desired output is supposed to represent?

Comment: P.S. re your edit...if you think the title is wrong, then change the title, instead of writing a long explanation of it :-)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, those were the outputs..`else if` I am trying to push a `0` value to the `data` property if a certain `category` does not have a value on `["series"]["name"]`

Comment: Ok so from your sample I can see what you were expecting. What result are you getting currently for that?

Comment: The index of the `data` represents the index of the `category` also. Example, `data: ["1",0,0,0]` that means the first value `1` is for category `Typhoon Sample 2000` `0` for `Typhoon Abra 2015` and so on.

Comment: Yes I understand that. And I can see from your question what result you desired. Now, again (for the 3rd time of asking), what result do you currently get from your code when you run it?

Comment: @ADyson `{"category":["Typhoon Sample 2000","Typhoon Abra 2015","No Event ","Holloween 2018"],"series":[{"name":"Entertainment","data":["1",0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Heavy Rainfall Warning and Advisory","data":["1",0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Daily Post","data":["1",0,0,0,"1"]},{"name":"Weather Forecast","data":["1",0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Actual Docs","data":["2",0,0,0,0]}]}`

Comment: It would be much better to edit that into the question itself. So the issue specifically is that you get 5 results instead of 4, correct? It would have been much quicker to say that immediately instead of saying "I have a problem", or "it's wrong"... :-)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I edited my question. My `else if` condition is wrong, probably. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite sure about your original logic - there were too many flaws to make it easy to fix, so instead I did a complete rewrite:

```
//prefetch all the DB rows, because we'll be looping them twice
$data2 = $result_select->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

//next, populate the series and category lists by looking through the data
foreach ($data2 as $row) {
    $evennt = $row["event_name"]." ".$row["year_of_event"];
    if (!in_array($evennt, $dbdata["category"])){
        $dbdata["category"][]=$evennt;
    }

    $ccat = $row["category_name"];
    $category_names = array_column($dbdata["series"], 'name');  
    if (!in_array($ccat, $category_names)){
        $dbdata["series"][] = array(
             'name' => $ccat,
             'data' => []
        );
    }
}

//now process the information to produce the "data" array
foreach ($dbdata["series"] as $serKey => $ser)
{
  foreach ($dbdata["category"] as $catKey => $cat)
  {
    $dbdata["series"][$serKey]["data"][$catKey] = 0; //default value

    foreach ($data2 as $rowKey => $row)
    {
      $rowCat = $row["event_name"]." ".$row["year_of_event"];
      $rowName = $row["category_name"];

      if ($rowName == $ser["name"] && $rowCat == $cat) {
        $dbdata["series"][$serKey]["data"][$catKey] = intval($row["cnt"]);
      }
    }
  }
}

echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

A demo (using static data instead of SQL row data) can be found here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6744c95bbbc0043cc015dc10069c7e045154d03c

Comment: I haven't tested if this works and I also haven't benchmarked it and it may just solve the issue and be ok-ish. But just generally speaking 4 nested control structures, 3 of which are loops = code smell. Or in clearer words, I'd never let it go past a code review. :)

Comment: @markus I agree it's not ideal, but the transformation the OP wants to do is quite...interesting, shall we say. There are probably ways to make the code nicer and possibly optimise performance, or maybe better use of SQL can be made...but I wasn't inclined to spend all day on a question like this TBH. At least now OP has a workable algorithm and maybe they can then improve on the process themselves by using some array functions etc. Or be my guest if you want to make a better fist of it yourself. P.S. the sandbox link will let you test it (saving the DB code, of course) :-)